# Failing an akka-stream graph if a downstream branch fails

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I'm not really sure how to ask the question. What I basically want to know is if it's possible to get this graph to return a failure, even though its output is upstream of the failure:

```
def flow(n: String) = Flow[Int].map{v => println(s"$n: $v"); v + 1}

val g = Source.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit b =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val broadcast = b.add(Broadcast[Int](2))
    val source = b.add(Source.single(1))

    source ~> flow("A") ~> broadcast

    broadcast.out(1) ~> flow("B") ~> flow("C").mapAsync(1){ _ => Future.failed(new Exception())} ~> Sink.foreach[Int](f => println("OK"))

    SourceShape(broadcast.out(0))
})
```